# Name and rules of Japanese card game

Tags: identify-this-game

While in Japan recently, a Japanese colleague taught me an excellent card game.

It involved a standard 52 card deck, and the game play proceeded like Uno in that each player could lay a card whose suit or number matched the top card on the discard pile.  However, the most important difference is that in this game your opponent can not end on a card which matches with any of the following operations on your cards: average, sum, geometric average, difference (2 cards) multiple, etc.  In addition, many of the cards have special meanings such as reverse, opponent shows cards, draw two, etc.

My colleague told me that this was a common game for him and his school mates during high school.  I've spent a while googling, and I can't seem to come up with the name or official rules.

What is the name of the game?  What are the official rules?

Answer (score 2):

Might it be Crazy Eight? (or Crates, Switch, Swedish Rummy, Last One, Rockaway, Mau-Mau or Pesten).

It has the most rules you mention, like reverse, draw two. Looks like UNO.

The last card rule might be a kind 'house rule', because there are a lot of variants of this card game all over the world.

http://www.pagat.com/eights/crazy8s.html

In the japanese wikipedia article, its saying also Crazy Eights. Article translated by Google Translate.

https://translate.google.nl/translate?hl=nl&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fja.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B8%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88